# Contrapositive clarification

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Let's say I have this statement:

∀ real numbers x, if −x is not irrational, then x is not irrational.

Which one of the following statements is equivalent to this?  [because −(−x) = x],

1.∀ real numbers x, if x is rational, then −x is rational.

2.∀ real numbers x, if -x is rational, then x is rational.

I thought it was the second one..but apparently it's the first one. If it's the second, can someone explain why? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because "Not irrational" means rational. And the "not" sign is a negation of the entire clause. So

> -(x is not irrational) $\implies$ x is not irrational $\equiv$ -(x is rational) $\implies$ (x is rational).

Comment: Wait, so is the correct contrapositive of the statement the first one or the second one?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Philosophy/Logic/ProofTheory/Proof_by_ContrpositionExamples.htm

Comment: So the second proof in that link must be wrong, right?

Comment: I'm a little confused because they said it was the first one :/

Comment: It's the second of the two that's correct.